# Como ordernar uma busca no MySQL com data no formato d-m-Y?

Tags: mysql

A data no meu banco está salva da seguinte maneira `dia-mês-ano`. Gostaria de saber como posso ordenar por data utilizando esse formato de data.

Comment: Esse campo é do tipo `date` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se os dados estão armazenados em string (campo char ou varchar), talvez não haja necessidade de conversões apenas para ordenação, então você pode simplesmente usar substrings, que são rápidas de se processar:

Se tiver separador na data (dd-mm-aaaa), pode ser assim:

```
SELECT * FROM basededados
   ORDER BY 
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 7, 4), 
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 4, 2),
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 1, 2)
```

Se for sem separadores (ddmmaaaa), basta ajustar os índices:

```
SELECT * FROM basededados
   ORDER BY
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 5, 4), 
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 3, 2),
      SUBSTR( campoComAData, 1, 2)
```

Basicamente, estamos dizendo via `ORDER BY`: "ordene por Ano, depois pelo Mês, e por fim pelo Dia".

- `SUBSTR( string, inicio, qtd)` extrai o pedaço da string começando por "inicio" e pegando "qtd" caracteres.

Comment: @Miguel Angelo Tá vendo, não é só com você que acontece.

Answer (score 5):

Se a data está armazenada como texto, você pode usar a função [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) do MySQL:

```
SELECT data 
FROM tabela
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(data, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta apenas adicionar o formato com [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) na lista de campos e depois ordernar:

```
SELECT date_format(data, '%d/%m/%Y') FROM datas ORDER BY data DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `mensagens` order by date(concat(ano,'-', mes,'-',dia)) asc
```

Assim, adeque ao seu modelo