# Ordenar os últimos cadastros de acordo com a data de registro

Tags: mysql, order-by

Ordenar os últimos anúncios cadastrado no mysql, com as datas mais próximas da data atual utilizando PHP
O tipo do campo (data) no mysql está como (date)

Esta é minha *query*:

```
SELECT * FROM frame_anuncio WHERE ativo = 'Sim' ORDER BY destaque ASC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo;
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como obter no SQL o último registro inserido de acordo com sua data](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13125/como-obter-no-sql-o-ultimo-registro-inserido-de-acordo-com-sua-data)

Comment: @NULL Não. Ele está falando de MySQL, não SQL Server.

Comment: Essa pergunta pode te ajudar tanto a buscar de forma ordenada quanto em um formato personalizado [**Como ordernar uma busca no MySQL com data no formato d-m-Y?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12238/como-ordernar-uma-busca-no-mysql-com-data-no-formato-d-m-y?rq=1)

Comment: o sql estou fazendo assim:
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM frame_anuncio WHERE ativo = 'Sim' ORDER BY destaque ASC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo")or die(mysql_error());

Mas o problema é que que os últimos anúncios cadastrados não ficam em primeiro lugar na listagem

Comment: @user3081 Você está ordenando do menor para o maior troque o ASC por DESC.

Comment: @NULL Isso não tem nada a ver, cara. Esse `destaque`, a princípio, não tem nenhuma relação com data.

Comment: Se eu trocar o ASC por DESC os anúncios em destaques não ficam no topo da listagem...

Comment: O destaque são anúncios com fotos, ou seja, tem que listar primeiro os anúncios com fotos depois o resto...e todos tem que estar ativos

Comment: qual o nome do seu campo data?

Comment: O nome do campo data é: data e o tipo é: date

Comment: @user3081 Editei minha resposta. Veja se te ajuda. Se te ajudar, marque como resolvido - andei acompanhando você e parece que não é algo que você está habituado a fazer. Se te ajudam, ajude-nos a continuar te ajudando. =)

Comment: @user3081 até hoje eu não localizei onde que marca como resolvido...onde é?

Comment: @user3081 Na resposta, logo abaixo das setas para cima e para baixo que se localizam na parte superior esquerda, existe um botão de "positivo". Clique nele.

Comment: Do lado esquerdo da resposta vc vai ver uns sinais de coreto de cor cinza, clica nele

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `ORDER BY` na sua query para isso, dessa forma:

`SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY date DESC`

Onde:

- `id` = dado à ser retornado;
- `table` = tabela à ser consultada;
- `data` = data do registro no banco de dados;
- `DESC` = retornar de forma decrescente, do maior para o menor – usando a lógica de dias: traga 30 antes de 29, justamente o que você deseja.

---

Me baseando na edição do seu post, faça o seguinte:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM frame_anuncio WHERE ativo = 'Sim' ORDER BY destaque ASC, data DESC LIMIT $inicio, $maximo")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Obrigado @Caesar pela edição! Nem me toquei que tivera colocado `WHERE` no lugar de `ORDER BY`.